# how to track 2 websites with google analytics

Tags: google-analytics

I have a google blog that I am tracking using google analytics for about a year.

Last week I have started a new blog and I wanted to track it too using my GA account.

What I did is to create another profile for the new blog and I put the tracking code in the new blog.

I probably missed something because when I look on the reports they are the same on both profiles.

How can I make each profile show only the information related to its blog?

Answer (score 0):

Admin-> {{PROFILE} -> Filters -> Include traffic by Hostname (equals {{DOMAINNAME}}) -> save -> repeat for other profile with other domainname.